# Get data from PHP to JavaScript to set position of each post on front page

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-field, loop, javascript

I've created a custom post type called project for my Wordpress theme, which works fine. Each project has several custom fields, including a set of x and y values that indicate where the project should show on the front page (see the style section of the code below: I know it's not working but I'm showing what I want to achieve in pseudo code).

I could display the x value as `<?php the_field('x'); ?>` and  `<?php the_field('y'); ?>`, as defined by the WordPress's Advanced Custom Field's documentation. However, how do I get the x and y value from PHP to the JavaScript, so I can use them to set the `left` and `top` value of the div that indicates where they should be on the front page?

Considering that there are many projects and I'm getting different sets of xs and ys in a loop, I'm thinking about writing all the x and y values into an external json file, and then load them back with JavaScript. Is this a feasible option, considering WordPress's structure? Or is there a better option to get these pairs of x and y values from PHP to JavaScript? I know AJAX is always an option, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way, as I can almost get these exact value pairs in DOM already...

```
<?php  

    $args = array(
        "post_type" => "project"
    );

    $projects = new WP_Query($args);

    while($projects->have_posts()){
        $projects->the_post();
?>

    <a class="project" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="top:x'px'; left: y'px'">
        <p><?php the_field("title"); ?></p>
    </a>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could output them as inline [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) instead of left/top, and then use those to set the position in either CSS or Javascript.

PHP:

```
<a class="project" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="—-x-position: <?php the_field('x'); ?>; —-y-position: <?php the_field('y'); ?>;'">
    <p><?php the_field("title"); ?></p>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.project {
    top: var(—-x-position);
    left: var(—-y-position);

    /* or CSS grid: */
    grid-row-start: var(—-x-position);
    grid-column-start: var(—-y-position);
}
```

They’re also accessible in JS, if you need them:

```
var x_position = element.style.getPropertyValue("--x- position");
```

This will be much more manageable for responsive design since you won’t have to override inline styles with `!important`, but inputting such specific x/y values is generally a bad idea and you’re probably better off not intermingling presentation quite so directly with your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_localize_script()` function to pass value into js.
For example

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts' );

public function my_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', ['jquery'] );
    wp_localize_script( 'custom-script', 'myScript', [
        'var_a' => 'value_a',
        'var_b' => 'another value',
    ] );
}
```

And in your custom_script.js you can get the value like these

```
console.log(myScript.var_a) // will return `value_a`
console.log(myScript.var_b) // will return `another value`
```